# Firebase Storage upload of img dont work -> Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I try to use firebase storage for the first time. My goal is to upload img to the storage.

Console shows this err:

> "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0:
>   Expected Blob or File.", serverResponse_: null, name_:
>   "FirebaseError"}

```
 export default function ImgUpload() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState([]);

  console.log('img', img);

  const handleUpload = () => {
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child(`images/${img.name}`)
      .put(img)
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        console.log('what');
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Input onChange={setImg} type="file" value={img} />
      <Button onClick={e => handleUpload(e)} type="submit">
        Upload
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have also find this in documentation:

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API 
ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {   
console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!'); });
```

I cant figure out how to set it to work even with this.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick check of the ReactJS documentation on [the file input tag](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag) you can get the actual file with `this.fileInput.current.files[0]`.

So that'd means it'd look something like this for you:

```
let file = this.fileInput.current.files[0];
firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child(`images/${file.name}`)
  .put(file)
```

With this in the JSX:

```
<input type="file" ref={this.fileInput} />
```